# Homology of cylinder relative to its bounding circles

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

I want to compute the relative homology groups $H_q(X,A)$, where $X=S^1\times[0,1]$ is a cylinder and $A=S^1\times\{0,1\}$ is the space containing the two bounding circles of $X$.

I showed that $H_q(X)=H_q(A)=0$ for $q>1$ and $H_1(X)=H_0(X)=\mathbb Z$ and $H_1(A)=H_0(A)=\mathbb Z^2$. This gave me $H_q(X,A)=0$ for $q>2$ and an elementary theorem states $H_0(X,A)=0$.

However, the cases $q=1$ and $q=2$ trouble me. The long exact homology sequence is $$0\to H_2(X,A)\to\mathbb Z^2\to\mathbb Z\to H_1(X,A)\to\mathbb Z^2\to\mathbb Z\to 0.$$ But from this alone, I cannot uniquely determine the homology groups (if I am correct, they must have the same rank and the rank is $\leq 2$). I could look at the groups themselves (rather than only relying on the exactness of the sequence above), but don't really know how to do that.

Comment: It may be useful to see that $H_i(A)=H_i(S^1\times\{0\})\oplus H_i(S^1\times \{1\}$ and that the inclusions $S^1\times\{0\}\to X$ and $S^1\times\{1\}\to X$ are homotopy equivalences. This should give you what the maps $\mathbb{Z}^2\to\mathbb{Z}$ are in the long exact sequence.

Comment: The map $H_q(A)\to H_q(X)$ is $i^{(0)}_*+i^{(1)}_*$, where $i^{(k)}: S^1\times\{k\}\to X$ is the inclusion ($k\in\{0,1\}$). The maps $i^{(k)}_*$ are isomorphisms, so the kernel of $i^{(0)}_*+i^{(1)}_*$ has rank $1$, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Well, that seems much easier than I expected it to be... Thank you!